# How to read only first n rows of parquet files to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, parquet

I want to read only first n number of rows in pandas.I pasted the below code which I've tried.

```
def s3_read_file(src_bucket_name,s3_path,s3_filename):
    try:
        src_bucket_name ="lla.analytics.dev"
        s3_path = "bigdata/dna/fixed/cwp/dt={}/".format(date_fmt)
        result = s3.list_objects(Bucket=src_bucket_name, Prefix=s3_path)  #getting dictionary
        for i in result["Contents"]:
            s3_filename = i['Key']
            #print(s3_filename)
            res = s3.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket_name, Key=s3_filename)  #s3://lla.analytics.dev/bigdata/dna/fixed/cwp/dt=2021-12-05/file.parquet
            #print(res)
            #df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(res['Body'].read()))
            #print(df)
            pf = spark.read.parquet().limit(1) 
            logger.info("****")
            logging.info('dataframe head - {}'.format(pf.count()))
            logger.info("****")
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)
```

I'm facing the below error: I tried with pyspark also but not getting

```
ERROR:root:read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nrows'
```

I also tried with the below one but BytesIO is not taking two arguments.

```
#df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(s3_obj['Body'].read(),nrows = 10))
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(s3_obj['Body'].read()),nrows = 10)`

Comment: @user17242583 pls check the above code...I tried the same but I'm not getting.(error : ERROR:root:read_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nrows'). Is there any other way to get the n rows?

Comment: I don't think it's an option, either in the pandas API (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) nor in the pyarrow engine API (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html), or the fastparquet  engine API (https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id0)

Comment: One issue is you're reading the data in as a string first. Try just passing the file path in with `pd.read_parquet('s3://testpavi/Bigdata/DNA/fixed/cwp/dt=2021-12-06/testdata.parquet')`

Comment: I'm not supposed to hardcode the path directly..because everytime it will change. I'm getting the files from s3 and then reading the file as dataframe. So I should use get object and  using BytesIo to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good place to start.
You can pass a subset of columns to read, which can be much faster than reading the whole file (due to the columnar layout):

```
pq.read_table('example.parquet', columns=['one', 'three'])
Out[11]: 
pyarrow.Table
one: double
three: bool
----
one: [[-1,null,2.5]]
three: [[true,false,true]]
When reading a subset of columns from a file that used a Pandas dataframe as the source, we use
```

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could write a loop and use read_row_group.

[https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#:~:text=row%20groups%20with-,read_row_group,-%3A](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#:%7E:text=row%20groups%20with-,read_row_group,-%3A)

```
parquet_file.num_row_groups
Out[22]: 1

parquet_file.read_row_group(0)
Out[23]: 
pyarrow.Table
one: double
two: string
three: bool
__index_level_0__: string
----
one: [[-1,null,2.5]]
two: [["foo","bar","baz"]]
three: [[true,false,true]]
__index_level_0__: [["a","b","c"]]
```